# Are my hoses safe?

Tags: watering, water, safety, hoses

We recently got some Apex 25-foot long (½-inch in diameter) blue hoses from Walmart that are supposed to be safe for drinking purposes. However, when I first turn it on in order to water my plants and such, the water seems fizzy or foamy for about twenty seconds each time (well, once a day or so). Is this really safe for me or my plants? I'm not sure if this will continue indefinitely, but it's been three or four weeks, now. I have three of them hooked together (but it still foamed with two). Our old hoses never did that, and they probably weren't meant for drinking.

Edit: The site asked me if the other question solved my problem. It is a similar question, but it didn't solve the issue, as my question was specifically about the fizzy/foamy quality of the water from a specific kind of hose—not about the safety/toxicity garden hoses generally, without regard to fizziness/foaminess (and without regard to whether the hose is advertised as safe for drinking). So, I can't honestly say the other Q/A answered my question  (although I do understand if others feel they are too similar to keep apart, or if they don't feel the question is a good one to remain open).

Comment: Please send the information attached to the hoses from Walmart.  Seriously, only white white white hoses are for drinking water for us and animals.  If these are blue and you are already seeing chemical reactions we need to pursue this issue.  What kind of water are you using?  City water should never be used to drink or cook with.  Isn't that sad!!

Comment: The hose has a white interior, and a blue exterior (and a white connector). I think I found part of the issue. It says not to use it with hot water (and to run it for several minutes before drinking from it). Hoses always get hot and spew hot water for a little bit here. Hrmm. I don't trust it even so, though. How do you know about white hoses? @stormy

Comment: Thanks Sue. :) @stormy Or you could delete it and put it in your answer, as a source, without the rant. :) The rest of the comment is pertinent, I think.

Comment: I definitely went off the reservation, whew.  I used to multi  task beautifully but looks like I should not try multi tasking anymore.  Took off the rant.  whew.  Sorry.

Comment: @stormy, why do you say city water should never be used to drink or cook with? Are you referring to ALL cities and towns, even those with examplary records and awards for the safest and best tasting water? Curious to know, not to start a debate.

Comment: Who judges the tests/findings?  Fluoride is pretty much standard addition to tap water.  'Good for our teeth'...is that in your water?  How they got away with using our municipal water supplies as a dumping ground for this vastly toxic compound, a waste product...from mining or manufacture of aluminum?  I am fuzzy on this, but not at all about fluoride is a toxic compound they put in our water and rationalize this addition because it was said to help our teeth.  I've not found one single article that even addresses the reasons this horribly toxic fluoride is routinely added to our water.

Comment: @Jude There is chlorine in our water that luckily dissipates quickly if allowed access to the air.  Used on plants it is another addition to the salt accumulation.  Heavy metals, what did you find on the tests that  was deemed  a 'safe' level and supported by your municipality?  Great water has very different definitions and I don't like what is passing for 'great water' these days.   If they can add fluoride to our water and have been doing this for 6 or 7 decades?  What else are they not  telling us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these hoses are not WHITE, drinking water from them is not safe.  Garden hoses are notorious for carcinogens.  Says right on their labels.  Hoses meant for residential purposes, drinking water even for animals is white.  These are the same hoses meant for recreational vehicles.  All other colors of hoses are carcinogenic.  I only use white hoses to water my horses!  White hoses with a blue line down the side.  Maybe red...but pretty sure about the blue line.

Also never reuse plastic water bottles, baby bottles made of plastic, put any plastic in the microwave to heat.

Not a great expense considering health of animals to include your kids.

Comment: Do you mean the interior, the exterior, or both must be white?

Comment: Mine does say "Drinking water safe" on it.

Comment: @Shule I looked up this hose, and yes it does say its drinking water safe - but walmart also publishes a disclaimer saying information provided is the manufacturer's responsibility. Its sold as drinking water safe, and in the UK its an offence to advertise features which are inaccurate on goods for sale, not sure if that's true where you are. But there's no way of anyone on here knowing whether that's true, so you either trust what the manufacturer says, or you don't, I'm afraid.

Comment: Exactly, what I was taught was only those brutally white hoses were made for drinking safe water.  Sure, that could change but I love love  love this disclaimer!  And the idea you portray...is critical.

Comment: I never seen white one.  But in Europe, there is clear labels (fork and knife) and something written if the recipients and hoses are apt for aliments (and this usually is done for "industrial use", but still found on normal shops).  Making some wine, I'm used to observe it, and I found that few yellow hoses that I use are usable for aliments (which I will not use anyway: outdoor, sun, and long hoses so not really cleanable are not good.).

Answer (score 3):

> when I first turn it on in order to water my plants and such, the water seems fizzy or foamy for about twenty seconds each time (well, once a day or so).

Nothing to get excited about. Dissolved gases in water that's cool since it's been in the water mains underground coming out of solution as the water warms up sitting in the hose.

You can see exactly the same thing if you set a glass of cold water out on the counter - little bubbles form and some stick to the sides of the glass. Cold(er) water can hold more dissolved gas than warm(er) water can.

Answer (score 2):

The drink water is not always 100% water with some mineral/salts.
It is just safe to drink.

Having seen some aqueduct, I can say that there are some lichens, mosses and seaweeds.
These are 100% safe, especially in cold and dark environment.
But on hoses (more light, warmer), they could be more lively (and die) so such "plants" could create some gases and waxes.
You probably see some of these byproducts.
I consider them safe, but I would really prefer not to drink from hoses.

Additionally water in hoses change pressure and temperature, so there are other effects: CO2 and calcium carbonate could dissolve and react.  See in geology, e.g., the calc-tufa, which is constantly created by slow sources going to lower pressure (outdoor).  This take time, but when you turn off water, there is some time, to have some reactions.

Why not on the old hoses?  I think because it was old, so less glossy, thus probably there were more deposit and few release of larger material.
Note: this foam (as I supposed in previous paragraphs) is made by very very very tiny particles, so the deposit are perceptible only on long term, and when they release larger particle, you doesn't see them, but neither the foam.

In general I would say it is (in Europe) safe. Carcinogens materials are banned since a lot of time, and release of chemicals must be within certain limits (hoses are considered household object, so controlled).  Just don't drink every day from it.